# Android - Adding Sound to my Alphabet app

Tags: android

I have been trying to add sound to my alphabet android application, but I don't seem to have been successful. Below is my code.

```
public class Sound extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ImageView b;
    private ImageView t;
    private ImageView j;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.alphabet);

        b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.b);
        t=(ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.t);
        j=(ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.j);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                b();
            }

        });


        setup();

        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                t();
            }               
        });
        setup2();
        j.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                j();
            }
        });
        setup3();
    }
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stop();
    }

    private void stop() {
        mp.stop();

    }

    private void b() {
        mp.stop();
        loadClip();
        mp.start();

        b.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void t() {
        mp.stop();
        loadClip2();
        mp.start();

        t.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void j() {
        mp.stop();
        loadClip3();
        mp.start();

        j.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void loadClip() {

        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }
    private void loadClip2() {

        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.t);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }

    private void loadClip3() {

        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.j);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        loadClip();
        b.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void setup2() {
        loadClip2();
        t.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void setup3() {
        loadClip3();
        j.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void goBlooey(Throwable t) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder
            .setTitle("Exception!")
            .setMessage(t.toString())
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .show();
    }
}
```

Would you please be so kind to take a look on my code and let me know where or what is missing.
All the images are in the drawable and all clips are in the raw.
Regards.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I have created an alphabet app, I want when images are clicked to give a sound of the alphabet. I have created the above code, but when I click the images there is no sound.

Comment: I know that much, but try to locate the actual problem by debugging or reasoning. Don't post entire classes.

Answer (score 1):

A quick skim through your code and I would say your mp doesn't exist in order to be stopping it before loading another clip on the first run.

At the top put
private MediaPlayer mp=null;

then on every line where it says mp.stop(); change it to if(mp!=null) mp.stop();

Comment: Still not working. I have done all you suggested. Still no sound.

Comment: Are the sound file formats mp3 or wav? is the sound turned up on your test device? do you get any messages from your "goBlooey" function? does any thing appear in logcat?

Comment: The app is in two components, one to play animation with sound (this part is working properly) and the other one is manually so that when the user clicks an image hears the sound (pronunciation). Nothing on the logcat.